# Scala subclass pattern match

Tags: scala, functional-programming, subclassing

I'm trying to run code from the book "Functional Programming in Scala" which seems to be made for an older version of scala (download from [here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/errorhandling/01.answer.scala)). tmp.scala:

```
sealed trait Option[+A]
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A] 
case object None extends Option[Nothing]

trait Option[+A] {
    /* returns None if None, or function applied to the some object */
    def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
      case None => None
      case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
    }
}
```

The errors this throws are:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-20161021-070700-8684ae8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112).
scala> :load tmp.scala

tmp.scala:17: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : None.type
 required: Option[A]
             case None => None
                  ^
tmp.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : None.type
 required: Option[B]
             case None => None
                          ^
tmp.scala:18: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Some[A(in class Some)]
 required: Option[A(in trait Option)]
             case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                  ^
tmp.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[B]
 required: Option[B]
             case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                                 ^
```

I tried all sorts of codefu on this, but to no avail, it seems like it's not detecting the subclasses properly due to outdated syntax?

Comment: The `Option` trait above is defined twice.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Zajac, I removed the first declaration (same error though).

Comment: It compiles just fine for me. Where are you trying to compile this? In a file or the REPL? What Scala version (though I don't think it should matter)?

Comment: @jwvh, added version info: 2.12

Comment: Can you show us the whole file? The line numbers in your error message don't match the code you posted.

Comment: I changed it back to faulty code with the two declarations. This is how I understood to write it based on the book, so I guess my question relates more to how to write this function properly?

Comment: You have a [code template](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/errorhandling/Option.scala#L6-L18) for the exercise in that repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:paste file.scala`, which pastes the content, instead of `:load file.scala`, which interprets each line.