# What does not compile?

Tags: scala

I have a trait as follow:

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {

  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
  }

}

case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

When I try to compile I've got following error:

```
scala> :load "src/Option.scala"
Loading src/Option.scala...
src/Option.scala:17: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : None.type
 required: Option[A]
           case None => None
                ^
src/Option.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : None.type
 required: Option[B]
           case None => None
                        ^
src/Option.scala:18: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Some[A(in class Some)]
 required: Option[A(in trait Option)]
           case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                ^
src/Option.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[B]
 required: Option[B]
           case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                               ^
src/Option.scala:11: error: illegal inheritance from sealed class Option
       case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
                                           ^
src/Option.scala:11: error: illegal inheritance from sealed class Option
       case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Why?

I am new in scala world and can not differ if the `map` is function or a method? How can I use map?

Comment: Use :paste file.scala, which pastes the content, instead of :load file.scala, which interprets each line.

Comment: possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900391/scala-subclass-pattern-match)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala subclass pattern match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900391/scala-subclass-pattern-match)